# Permissions issue in Windows 7 - System32

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I am trying to copy and replace a file into the System32 folder.  I have given my account ownership of the folder, but still cannot copy and replace a file over to this folder!  Why is this?  This is the only user account on the machine.

Giving myself full permissions afterwards yields "error Applying Security" for each individual folder/file.

> An error occurred while applying
>   security information to:
>   (file/folder).  Access is denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because the permissions are not inherited by default anymore, so changing the owner to yourself on System32 does not automatically set you as the owner to every item in the subfolders and therefore you can't change permissions en masse.

Comment: Unreal, this is it.  Did not know that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even though you the Owner, does not automatically give you permission.  Go back and seek out the Permissions and Effective permissions tabs.  Add your own username.

Comment: Giving myself full permissions, I get "An error occurred while applying security information to: (lists every possible file/folder one by one).  Access is denied

Comment: Could it be you have missed the box which deals with sub-folders and files?  It's easy for me to say, but I am sure this will work if you check the right boxes and keep trying different combinations.  Have faith!

Comment: One more idea, would Safe Mode help?